# New Tab screen on Edge changed to Chinese and does not change back to English

Tags: language, microsoft-edge

For some mysterious reason (I do not know how), the New Tab screen on Edge changed to Chinese and does not change back to English, or any language, despite my attempts to do so (by using the options under the gear icon) and even after clearing the page cache and cookies.

Can someone help me to change it back?

[image: New tab page displayed in Chinese]

[image: Modifying the language does now work]

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone help me to change it back?

Clicking on the `Page Settings` button will allow you to change the language of the Startup page under the Advanced options.  However, you might also verify for a second time, your Bing search options are correct as you are logged into your account based on your own screenshot.

[image]

You might also change the settings of the Startup Page and verify it's not in a custom format.

I was able to recreate your configuration entirely using `Page Settings`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, as I mentioned in the question and the in the comments (well, the comments from the other day that do not see anymore), I already did that and it did not work. And also, I checked Bing settings and they are correct.

Comment: @CodeAddict - I was able to change my language to Chinese, and switch it back, using this method. Have you tried removing the Edge user profile after you back it up? This could be a Edge group policy that is being applied.

Comment: If that worked with you, then I would say: lucky you :) I added a screen recording which shows that changing the language has no effect whatsoever. Not that the page refresh does not show, but you can see that gear icon flashing because the page refreshed.

Comment: "Have you tried removing the Edge user profile after you back it up?" I don't know how to back up the user profile. If that requires backing up folders and registry keys, I am less willing to go this path because I do not trust that Edge will be restored correctly if I wanted to go back to "normal".

Comment: "This could be a Edge group policy that is being applied." Which Group Policy? This PC is personal PC and does not connect to corporate networks or an Active Directory domain.

Comment: @CodeAddict - You can still enable group policies on personal machines.  For example before Legacy Edge was removed that’s how you were able to run both Legacy Edge and Chromium Edge on the same machine.

Comment: What I meant to say is that Group Policies do not apply themselves; it is either the PC is joined to a domain and AD sets the policies or I do it myself. In my case I did not touch the Group Policies and did not join a domain. Hence, the issue I am facing does not seem to be relate to Group Policies. In any case, I do not even know which Group Policy to change.

Comment: How you backup the profile is you copy the folder to another location.  A different way would be to create a temporary Windows user and see if the problem is recreated.

Comment: When I create a new profile in Edge, I can change the language to whatever I want.

Comment: Are you synchronizing the profile to a Microsoft Account by chance?

Comment: Yes, I am. The other PC that I am syncing with shows the correct language and region and I was able to change it to the language and region of my choice.